# How can I use Maven Artifact Resolver to list transitive dependencies?

Tags: java, apache, maven, dependencies, aether

I am working on an application for my company which needs to resolve dependencies for a maven project. This is a standalone application, not a maven plugin. The only thing I am trying to do at the moment is print the resolved dependencies to confirm that they were found. I am using [Apache Maven Model](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-model/) (`v4.0.0-alpha-2`), [Apache Maven Artifact Resolver](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/index.html) (`v1.8.2`), and [Maven Artifact Resolver Implementation](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/maven-resolver-impl/) (`v1.8.2`) to support my endeavor.

The initial setup is really what's nerfing me. I haven't had any luck finding update-to-date examples or documentation. This is the code I drafted up:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws LoadException, IOException, XmlPullParserException, DependencyResolutionException {
    MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
    Model model = reader.read(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\lc70844\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\pom.xml")));

    DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = new DefaultRepositorySystemSession();
    DefaultRepositorySystem repositorySystem = new DefaultRepositorySystem();

    for (Dependency dependency : model.getDependencies()) {
        DependencyRequest request = new DependencyRequest();
        request.setRoot(new DefaultDependencyNode(
                new org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency(toArtifact(dependency), dependency.getScope())));
        DependencyResult result = repositorySystem.resolveDependencies(session, request);
        result.getArtifactResults().stream().map(a -> a.getArtifact())
                .map(a -> a.getGroupId() + ":" + a.getArtifactId() + ":" + a.getVersion()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

It is  throwing an exception saying "repository system session's local repository manager cannot be null." This is pretty self-explanatory; we all know what I need to do. However, [`DefaultRepositorySystemSession#setLocalRepositoryManager(LocalRepositoryManager)`](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/DefaultRepositorySystemSession.html#setLocalRepositoryManager-org.eclipse.aether.repository.LocalRepositoryManager-) requires a `LocalRepositoryManager` parameter, which is what I am having trouble figuring out how to setup. The repository I want to use is the the local repo at: `%userprofile%/.m2/repository`.

I found a few similar questions pertaining to my issue, but they seem to have the wrong context or are using deprecated libraries to achieve their end. I am hoping for a reliable, up-to-date solution.

Hopefully I am least heading in the right direction. What more do I need to do to get my list of dependencies?

### EDIT

My current approach is to use [Maven Invoker](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/) to run `mvn dependency:list`, but this is only temporary and is not a real solution. It takes too long to spin up the Maven process, and parsing the log output to get file paths is not clean approach. I am working to make my application more efficient, and using Maven Invoker is not an efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have access to target `pom.xml` you can simply execute `mvn dependency:tree` which would print complete tree of all the dependencies along with their scopes (both explicitly specified and transitive).
The output looks like this:

```
[INFO] com.tsypanov:spring-boot-benchmark:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.33:compile
...
```

Alternatively, if you need to parse the output, it'd be easier with `mvn dependency:list` or `mvn dependency:build-classpath`. Pay attention, that this just prints the model and doesn't tell anything about whether particular dependency is resolved and cached in `.m2`, but you can check this with the output of `mvn dependency:classpath`: just split the output line looking like

```
[INFO] Dependencies classpath:
C:\Users\STsypanov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\STsypanov\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.3\spring-boot-2.6.3.jar;
```

with `;` and then check whether each file exists:

```java
String[] paths = classpath.split(";");
for (String path : paths) {
  var file = new File(path);
  if (file.exists()) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: This wasn't the answer I was looking for, but alas, it was the *only* answer. I guess I will have to keep doing things the slow way for now :(